# Styling 2 elements in a different way

Tags: css, styles

So i got stuck with this code snippet.
My problem is that the word "check" should be green (and only when its actually checked) but now the "checkbox label element" takes the style from the "inputfield label element".
Is there a way to stlye the 2 "label" elements ("checkbox label" and the "input field label") independent from each other?

```css
/*Input Field*/

.field {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: column-reverse;
      flex-flow: column-reverse;
}
label,
input {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
input {
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
input:placeholder-shown + label {
  cursor: text;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
          transform-origin: left bottom;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 2.125em) scale(1.5);
          transform: translate(0, 2.125em) scale(1.5);
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
input:focus + label {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
          transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
  cursor: default;
  color: #FF0000;
}
label {
  max-width: 66.666%;
  color: #ccc;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

/*Checkbox*/
[type='checkbox'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

[type='checkbox'] + label{
  --c-hl: dimgrey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--c-sel, var(--c-hl));
  font: 1.5rem/ 1 consolas, monaco, monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
  margin-right: .375em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--c-sel, var(--c-hl));
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--c-sel, transparent);
  content: "✔";
}
[type='checkbox']:focus + label, [type='checkbox']:hover + label {
  --c-hl: #239023;
}
[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  --c-sel: #239023;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
 
    <!--Input Field -->
    <div class="field">
   <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" autofill="autofill">
   <label for="fullname">Name</label>
 </div>
                   
    <!-- Chekcbox-->
    <input type='checkbox' id='check'/>
    <label for='check'>check</label>
                   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/7by8nkpL/1/

I just created new input with `id="new"` and edited label `for="new"` and added this code, you can see the id #new where I added it in css to make a special design.

```
    [type='checkbox']#new:focus + label, [type='checkbox']#new:hover + label {
      --c-hl: blue;
    }
    [type='checkbox']#new:checked + label {
        --c-sel: blue;
    }
    input#new:not(:placeholder-shown) + label, input#new:focus + label {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
        transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
        cursor: default;
        color: blue;
    }
```

Check this code

CSS:

```
/*Input Field*/

.field {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: column-reverse;
      flex-flow: column-reverse;
}
label,
input {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
input {
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
input:placeholder-shown + label {
  cursor: text;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
          transform-origin: left bottom;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 2.125em) scale(1.5);
          transform: translate(0, 2.125em) scale(1.5);
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
input:focus + label {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
          transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
  cursor: default;
  color: #ff00c4;
}
label {
  max-width: 66.666%;
  color: #ccc;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

/*Checkbox*/
[type='checkbox'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

[type='checkbox'] + label{
  --c-hl: dimgrey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--c-sel, var(--c-hl));
  font: 1.5rem/ 1 consolas, monaco, monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
  margin-right: .375em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--c-sel, var(--c-hl));
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--c-sel, transparent);
  content: "✔";
}
[type='checkbox']:focus + label, [type='checkbox']:hover + label {
  --c-hl: #000;
}
[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    --c-sel: #8d89b6;
}
[type='checkbox']#new:focus + label, [type='checkbox']#new:hover + label {
  --c-hl: blue;
}
[type='checkbox']#new:checked + label {
    --c-sel: #a20000;
}
input#new:not(:placeholder-shown) + label, input#new:focus + label {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
    transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
    cursor: default;
    color: #89ff10;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
     <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" autofill="autofill">
     <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>

<!-- Chekcbox-->
<input type='checkbox' id='check'/>
<label for='check'>check</label>
               <br>
<input type='checkbox' id='new'/>
<label for='new'>New one</label>
```

[image]